# TreeSet object removal does not work even after implementing Comparator

Tags: java, object, treeset

I have tried to implement AStar Algorithm in Java with Eclipse. My positions in the graph are represented by Objects. I use a TreeSet to store the positions and implemented a comparator for the object specific sorting. However at one line the code is supposed to remove the current object from the TreeSet, which does not work. I managed to use pollFirst() instead and the algorithm worked. However I could not find the reason why treeSet.remove(Object) should not work.

I added the boolean equals and compareTo. Both are true so according to equals and compareTo current is equal to openSet.first() however openSet.remove(current) is unable to remove current from openSet

I added the whole code! I tested it on codewars with huge test cases so the code works if I use pollFirst() instead of remove(current)

Edit: After reading the JavaDoc for Set Interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) I found the following warning:

> Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

I suspect this has to do with my problem. However it is still strange why the program works when I replace openSet.remove(current) with openSet.pollFirst()

Edit2: I changed the Comparator according to the suggestions by Loris Securo. Unfortunately it is still not working

```
public class Finder implements Comparable<Finder> {

public int i; // All integers are initialized to zero.
public int j;
public int id;
public int fScore; 
public int gScore;
public ArrayList<Finder> neighbours = new ArrayList<Finder>();
public Object character;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Finder [i=" + i + ", j=" + j + ", gScore=" + gScore + ",fScore =" + fScore + ", id=" + id
            + ", character=" + character + "]";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String a = "......\n" + "......\n" + "......\n" + "......\n" + "......\n" + "......";
    Object[] mazeParts = a.split("\n");
    System.out.println("mazeParts is " + Arrays.toString(mazeParts));
    Object[][] maze = new Object[mazeParts.length][];

    int r = 0;
    for (Object t : mazeParts) {
        System.out.println("t is " + t);
        maze[r++] = ((String) t).split("");
    }
    Finder[][] mazeOfnodes = new Finder[mazeParts.length][maze[0].length];
    int id = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("maze" + i + j + " is " + maze[i][j]);
            Finder node = new Finder(); 
            node.character = maze[i][j];
            node.i = i;
            node.j = j;
            node.id = id;
            mazeOfnodes[i][j] = node;
            id++;
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                node.fScore = heuristic(i, j, mazeOfnodes);
                node.gScore = 0;
            } else {
                node.fScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                node.gScore = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mazeOfnodes.length; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) {
            mazeOfnodes[i][j].neighbours = mazeOfnodes[i][j].findNeighbours(i, j, mazeOfnodes);
            System.out.println("mazeOfnodes is " + mazeOfnodes[i][j]);
        }
    }


}

public static int findWay(Finder[][] myMaze) {
    Finder goal = myMaze[myMaze.length - 1][myMaze.length - 1];
    TreeSet<Finder> openSet = new TreeSet<Finder>();
    openSet.add(myMaze[0][0]);
    TreeSet<Finder> closedSet = new TreeSet<Finder>();
    while (openSet.size() != 0) {
        Finder current = openSet.first();
        if (current == goal) {
            return current.gScore;
        }
        boolean equals = current.equals(openSet.first());
        boolean compareTo = (current.compareTo(openSet.first()) == 0);
        openSet.remove(current); //if I use openSet.pollFirst() the code   works fine. I tested it on Codewars with several huge test cases
        boolean success = openSet.remove(current);
        System.out.println("success is " + success);

        closedSet.add(current);
        for (Finder s : current.neighbours) {
            if (closedSet.contains(s)) {
                continue;
            }
            int tentative_gScore = current.gScore + 1;
            if (tentative_gScore >= s.gScore) {
                continue;
            }
            s.gScore = tentative_gScore;
            s.fScore = s.gScore + heuristic(s.i, s.j, myMaze);
            if (!openSet.contains(s) && !s.character.equals("W")) {
                openSet.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<Finder> findNeighbours(int i, int j, Finder[][] maze) {
    if (i > 0) {
        neighbours.add(maze[i - 1][j]);
    }
    if (i < maze.length - 1) {
        neighbours.add(maze[i + 1][j]);
    }
    if (j < maze.length - 1) {
        neighbours.add(maze[i][j + 1]);
    }
    if (j > 0) {
        neighbours.add(maze[i][j - 1]);
    }
    return neighbours;
}

public static int heuristic(int i, int j, Object[][] mazeFinal) {
    int distance = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mazeFinal.length - 1 - i, 2) + Math.pow(mazeFinal.length - 1 - j, 2));
    return distance;


    public int compareTo(Finder2 arg0) {
    if (this.fScore < arg0.fScore) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.id == arg0.id) { // If id is the same, fScore is the same too
        return 0;
    } else if (this.fScore == arg0.fScore) { //If id is different, fScore could still be the same
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Comparator` doesn't obey the rules. If `arg0.fScore == arg1.fScore && arg0.id < arg1.id` it should return -1.

Comment: No it schouldn't. arg0.fScore == arg1.fScore && arg0.id == arg1.id is correct. It guarantees that the treeSet can determine which elements are equal. From the javadoc "but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. "

Comment: Can the downvoters please elaborate how to improve the question?

Comment: @user207421 is right. Your comparator is broken in several ways. Also, please post a [mcve].

Comment: @shmosel I've added the whole code which works on Codewars with huge test cases. Could you elaborate why the comparator is broken?

Comment: Note the *minimal* part. Your comparator is broken because the contract requires that if `compare(a, b) < 0`, then `compare(b, a) > 0`. But you're returning -1 regardless of which `id` is greater.

Comment: @shmosel Yes because compareTo should only consider positions equal when fScore AND ID are equal. If that is not the case compareTo should only use fScore for sorting. If fScore is the same (this.fScore == arg0.fScore) I could either return -1 or 1 its arbitrarily because its just used to break ties..

Comment: No, it's not arbitrary. There's a contract and you're breaking it.

Comment: @shmosel Ok you were right, I changed the comparator accordingly but the problem persists. I suspect it has to do with the fact that Objects in Sets should not be changed. According to Java Doc "Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements, The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set."

Answer (score 1):

Your `compareTo` method doesn't work properly on a `TreeSet` because it doesn't satisfy the rule that if A > B then B < A.

In your case, if `fScore` are equals (and `id` are different) then A > B, but also B > A.

A `TreeSet` is backed by a self balancing binary tree that is built based on the `compareTo` method.

Because of that inconsistency the tree might be unable to find a specific object, since it wouldn't be able to correctly choose to perform a search on the left branch or on the right branch.

For example, if you have 3 objects A, B and C with the same `fScore`:

1. you add A, now it is the root
2. you then add B, the `compareTo` says that it is greater than A, so it could generate this tree (now the root is B):

   ```
     B
    /
   A
   ```
3. you then add C, the `compareTo` says that it is greater than B, so it could generate this tree:

   ```
     B
    / \
   A   C
   ```
4. now you want to remove A, which is present, but, using the comparator, A is greater than B, so the tree checks the right branch, there it finds C and it stops, so the method is unable to find and delete A

`pollFirst` instead could simply pick the leftmost object, so it is always able to remove something, but the removed object is going to depend on the implementation.

This problem was also discussed in this blog post: [Algosome - Java: The misouse of a TreeSet](https://www.algosome.com/articles/java-tree-set-sort-misuse.html) which is based on this forum thread: [Java Programming Forum - TreeSet contains(obj) doe not behave as expected](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/collections-generics/31135-treeset-contains-obj-doe-not-behave-expected.html).

Comment: I changed my Comparator so that it should be consistent with the contract, so that if A > B, B < A. However it is still only working using pollFirst()